# Labels (category type) on left and right of bar chart using chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to place labels on both left and right sides of a horizontal bar chart?

The labels are sort of 'category' type, where the data is basically a measurement of where one is between the two categories (e.g., Introvert - Extrovert) so a score of 1 is closer to "Introvert" on the left, and a score of 10 is closer to "Extrovert" on the right.

Attaching a screenshot of what I've got now -- labels are only on the left, and so I have to sort of show the left/right indirectly by putting "Introverted<->Extroverted" instead of having them on the opposite sides.

[image]

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use two yAxes, one to the left and the other one to the right side, used to show "min/max" category labels.

In addition [datalabels plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) provides labelling over horizontal bars:

```js
var chartData = {
  labels: ['Extraversion', 'Anxiety', 'Tough', 'Indipendence'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'value',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(219, 20, 0, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(219, 20, 0, 0.8)',
    data: [60, 80, 55, 40],
  yAxisID: 'y0'
  }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
   legend: { display: false },
    scales: {    
      yAxes: [{
        id: "y0",
        weight: 1,
        position: "left",
        type: 'category',
        display: false,
        gridLines: {
         display: false
        },
        ticks: {
         display: false,
          padding: 0
        }
      },{
        id: "y1",
        weight: 0,
        position: "left",
        type: 'category',
        labels: ['Intro', 'Low', 'Rec', 'Accom'],
        gridLines: {
         display: false
        }
      },{
        id: "y2",
        position: "right",
        type: 'category',
        labels: ['Extra', 'High', 'Tough', 'Indipend'],
        gridLines: {
         display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
       id: "x1",
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'red',
        align: 'right',
        anchor: 'start',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          console.log(context)
           return chartData.labels[context.dataIndex];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

---

**Update:**

as alternative you can draw your own labels `onComplete` (no additional plugin needed). Here below is an example:

```js
var chartData = {
  labels: ['Extraversion', 'Anxiety', 'Tough', 'Indipendence'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'value',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(219, 20, 0, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(219, 20, 0, 0.8)',
    data: [60, 80, 55, 40],
    yAxisID: 'y0'
  }]
};
var y1Labels = ['Intro', 'Low', 'Rec', 'Accom'];
var y2Labels = ['Extra', 'High', 'Tough', 'Indipend'];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 50,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: "y0",
        weight: 1,
        position: "left",
        type: 'category',
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          fontSize: 14
        }
      }, {
        id: "y1",
        position: "right",
        type: 'category',
        labels: ['Extra', 'High', 'Tough', 'Indipend'],
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          padding: 30
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        id: "x1",
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 0,
      onComplete: function() {
        var chartInstance = this.chart;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(12, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.textBaseline="bottom"; 

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          console.log(chartInstance, meta);

          var x0 = chartInstance.scales.y0.right;
          var x1 = chartInstance.scales.y1.left;

          meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
            var label = y1Labels[index];
            var xOffset = x0 - 10 - ctx.measureText(label).width;
            var yOffset = bar._model.y - 15;
            ctx.fillText(label, xOffset, yOffset);

            var label = y2Labels[index];
            var xOffset = x1 + 10;
            var yOffset = bar._model.y - 15;
            ctx.fillText(label, xOffset, yOffset);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @beaver -- I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: @beavery -- I did it without the datalabels for now... it worked, except that the labels aren't properly aligned with the bars. Is there a way to adjust that so the 'rows' line up?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://trimergprogrms.wpengine.com/test-graph.html)

Comment: @ScottM - I updated my answer with an alternative solution

Comment: @ScottM - I updated (and corrected some errors) the code from your example and created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/jjrfz73L/. I don't know exact meaning of your categories and so I only reduced them to 24, equal to the number of data

Comment: thanks! That's getting closer. I notice two things: 1. because the display of the side labels is after the animation is complete, they "flash" when mousing over the chart; 2. it doesn't accommodate different numbers of datasets well -- is there a way to calculate the row height and place the labels dynamically based on that? Here's a jsfiddle with more datasets and the legend to allow hiding datasets - https://jsfiddle.net/asmphd/obp0u50z/ -- I'll see if I can mockup a full version of what I'm actually trying to accomplish fully (it's currently not public-facing).

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to place them dead-middle in the row like the "regular" tick labels (replacing the regular tick labels).

Comment: I've created a public facing version with identifying information removed - https://trimergprogrms.wpengine.com/16pf-results/ -- note that I have not applied your recent changes, but this will at least give the full context (which I now realize may make a difference). Also note that a lot of the data, labels, etc are actually loaded into the scripts via php (I know php a little better and had to do some data manipulation, etc).

Comment: You can operate on xOffset/yOffset to achieve your goal

Comment: Thanks @beaver -- I've tried using xOffset/yOffset, but I can't see how to make it so the labels don't move when I 'hide/reveal' datasets on the graph. So I can set the yOffset so they're in a good place, but if I hide datasets, the label moves down (or when I reveal datasets the label moves up)... plus the labels 'flash' when mousing over the graph bars.
Your code snippets do technically do what I was asking for, so for that I thank you and accept your answer... I'm hoping I can figure out the remaining issues so that it's usable in my particular context.